# Can two MAX7219 chips drive a 10x11 LED matrix?

Tags: led-matrix

I want to drive a 11x10 LED matrix.  Can two MAX7219 do this? Is there a way to have on MAX7219 handle a core of 8x8 LEDs and the other would drive the remaining 3 cols and 2 rows?

Comment: depends on the matrix..

Comment: Is this a matrix of 110 individual LEDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like each max7219 can handle 64 leds, so you should be able to drive your matrix as long as long as it's individual leds. If they're pre-wired into some kind of grid then it will depend on the grid.

Comment: Programming and mapping the pixels might be a bit of a chore though

Comment: Yes, 110 LEDs wired in rows and columns so that they can be mulitplexed.  I am using an Arduino and there is really great libraries written to drive the MAX7219 such as MD_MAX722x.   Problem is it assumes an 8x8 matrix.  How can I tell the second MAX7219 to use the remaining rows and columns around the 8x8 core?  I have this wired up and the second chip does not know what is going on - no output.  The 1st chip is driving the 8x8 fine.  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.